# How can I make the Twitter sharing button on my site tweet unique message with each page?

Tags: twitter, social-sharing-buttons

I had set up my Twitter button using this tool from Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet)

And I put it on every page of the website. But it generates the same message on every page. But ideally I would need it to generate a unique message and url per page so people can land on the page which is being shared.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are creating the code from twitter, If you have entered any url it will share that page content and url every time.

So the solution is just need to avoid the url option while your using twitter share button code , It will read the content from the current page and share current url.

Normally all the social share button using `og meta data` so set the og data properly some thing like

```
<meta name="description" content="meta description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="your page keywords" />
<meta name="og:title" content="Your page title nique" />
<meta name="og:type" content="type of content" />
<meta name="og:description" content="Description this will share on social media as a contnet." />
<meta name="og:url" content="http://www.walkswithme.net/smart-image-zoom-plugin-with-jquery" />
```

hope its make sense..

Comment: see my edit too for better idea

Comment: I am trying to figure it out :) .....how would I have the code if I don't want to hard-code the url for each page? Thank you!

Comment: simply just avoid og:url meta , otherwise set it using server side language if you using any cms it will have option to get current url

Comment: Figured it out with your help - thank you...much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Good luck :)